# Sending a SOAP request to FritzBox

Tags: c#, .net, soap, fritzbox

I'm trying to send a SOAP request to a FritzBox (WLAN router) using C#.
Currently I'm assembling the XML SOAP request by hand, since the server does not offer a WSDL file.

This is how I create the web request that I attach my XML to:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (@"http://fritz.box:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1");
webRequest.Headers.Add (@"SOAP:Action");
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
```

But when sending the request I get a WebException:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I'm pretty sure it has to do something with my URL, but I don't know how to fix it. The FritzBox documentation is rather bad :-/

Answer (score 1):

try this Code its work to get the External IP

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://fritz.box:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1");
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetExternalIPAddress");
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        //Create Stream and Complete Request             
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

        StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" s:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""> <s:Body><u:GetExternalIPAddress xmlns:u=""urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1"" /></s:Body></s:Envelope>");

        streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
        streamWriter.Close();
        //Get the Response    
        HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
        return resulXmlFromWebService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another example of a common UseCase: Get new IP Address

```
private string ReconnectFritzBox()
{
    string xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\">" +
        "<s:Body>" +
            "<u:ForceTermination xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1\" />" +
        "</s:Body>" +
    "</s:Envelope>";

    string resulXmlFromWebService = null;

    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://fritz.box:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1");
    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#ForceTermination");
    httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    httpRequest.ContentLength = xmldata.Length;

    using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        //Create Stream and Complete Request             
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(xmldata);
            streamWriter.Close();

            //Get the Response    
            var wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    return resulXmlFromWebService;
}
```

Full Code example is also on Github: [Link](https://github.com/codingyourlife/fritzbox.reconnect/)